# Does the JAVA compiler take care of new instantiations inside function scope?

Tags: java, android

Example:

```
//Type1:
function PointF someMethod(){
    return new PointF(10f, 10f);
}

//Type2:
private PointF funPointF = new PointF();
function PointF(){
    return funPointF.set(10f,10f);
}
```

Now my question is, is that for readability and actual coding the first example is much more friendly; how does the compiler handle the first result? Does it create the second automatically for use at run time or does it actually just create a new object everytime this method is called?

**EDIT
Yes it's JAVA.

Comment: is this actually Java? it doesn't *look* like Java.

Comment: Of course, when you run `new` it created the new object, BUT if the point is immutable and you want to have the constant for it, you should create the constant (`static final`) field, initialized in static initializer, which should be returned from this method.

Comment: @Zhuinden I think OP meant `function` to be just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, The Java complier automaically creates new object once you have instantiated

i.e. using the keyword `new` for creating a reference of new object.

```
function PointF someMethod(){
    return new PointF(10f, 10f);
}
```

In above method, The compiler has created a new object for `PointF` in the Heap as you have written `new PointF(10f, 10f)` and returning the value of same object.

Comment: So it's inefficient to use new then?

Comment: You don't need to create a new instance every time unless required, Go through singelton class/Instance variables as well where you can keep a single instance of your object.

Comment: I understand them completely, I was under the assumption that JAVA compiler might be smarter and realise that the variable is being reused.

Comment: AFAIK a new object will be created when you instantiate a new object.